# How to get rid of TypeError at /task_create/, quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Tags: django

I am on `django 4.0.4` and have a benign but annoying problem with the above error code.

Previous responses to similar questions don't help me.

When I backspace, (an incovenience a user may not think of) everything has actually gone well, the list and detail views are correctly updated.

The create form is however as it was as if it was not saved, and the view doesn't change to the detail view as suggested by the `get_absolute_url`, which may lead one to process it again.

The code from previous models is exactly the same where it matters. An example is the `TaskCreate` view which is giving the problem and the `ObjectiveCreate` view just before it which works as expected.

In the views, I find the user and his/her entity (even though there is one entity), and process that user as a supervisor1 and also automatically process the entity.

The error finds fault with the `TaskCreate` view's "`return super().form_valid(form)`" but not with that in the `ObjectiveCreate` view.

Here is the code for the two views

```
class ObjectiveCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Objective
    form_class = ObjectiveCreateForm
    template_name = "internalcontrol/objective_create_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):

        user = self.request.user
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        entity = profile.entity
        new_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user, entity=entity)
        form.instance.supervisor1 = new_profile
        form.instance.entity = entity
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):

        kwargs = super(ObjectiveCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["request"] = self.request
        return kwargs

class TaskCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Task
    form_class = TaskCreateForm
    template_name = "internalcontrol/task_create_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):

        user = self.request.user
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        entity = profile.entity
        new_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user, entity=entity)
        form.instance.supervisor1 = new_profile
        form.instance.entity = entity
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):

        kwargs = super(TaskCreate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["request"] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

The respective `get_absolute_url` for both models are:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(
        "internalcontrol:objective_detail",
        kwargs={"pk": self.pk},
    )
```

and

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return (
        reverse("internalcontrol:task_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk}),
    )
```

The traceback is as follows:

```
Internal Server Error: /task_create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 73, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 184, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 153, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)

  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\django projects\nguyena\internalcontrol\views.py", line 231, in form_valid
    return super().form_valid(form)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 136, in form_valid
    return super().form_valid(form)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 65, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 538, in __init__
    self["Location"] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)

  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\nguyena-QPBkFrkQ\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 139, in iri_to_uri
    return quote(iri, safe="/#%[]=:;$&()+,!?*@'~")

  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 871, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)

  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 896, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")

TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

[18/Apr/2022 17:08:13] "POST /task_create/ HTTP/1.1" 500 125026
```

Comment: Please share the traceback

Comment: Added the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the final address to which the user should be redirected.

To solve this problem, first edit the `get_absolute_url` function to return a `string`, not a `tuple`.

If it still does not work, try adding a `success_url` to the view with `reverse_lazy`

Comment: The second suggestion worked!